# Holding an experience variable to be read/written to throughout a program (python 3)

Tags: python, scope

I've been stuck trying to get a way to have an experience variable in my "game" that I am trying to get to work.
I have recently found out that I am able to import different Python files that I've created, which makes for much neater files instead of having EVERYTHING in one file.
I think I'm having trouble figuring out how to get global variables to work though. If someone can give me a solution *without using an external module, or creating a separate file* that would be great. I would like for all the variables to stay within .py files.

Here's what I thought would work. Maybe it will work, I just don't know how to do it correctly.
I want there to be three (or more) files. File 1 will be the main file. This will have the main menu and allow the player to go to other events. File 2 will contain the variable player_experience and will be equal to 0 (but will be added on to throughout the game). File 3+ will be events that can be done and in return, give experience. I need that experience variable to be able to be read throughout ALL the files, and can be added onto whenever needed.

I thought that by using the "global player_experience" at the top of all my files would make this work, but I was not able to get it to work.

If it makes any difference, I am only using definitions in my files. For example:

```
#file1.py
print('what do you want to do? 1 - game, 2 - check experience')
donow = input()
if donow == '1':
    game() 
if donow == '2':
    check_experience() #just pretend this is defined somewhere
```

the check_experience function will just print out the player's experience. But I would like this function to be able to be used throughout all the files. (which I think I can do by just defining the function in a file, and importing the funciton whenever I need it)

```
#file2.py
print('yay you beat the game, here's 500 experience')
player_experience += 500
print('You now have',player_experience,'experience.')
```

I'm sorry if this is a common question, I HAVE tried to do my own research on this, but I wasn't able to find anything without creating a separate configuration-type file, which is a bit beyond my abilities at the moment. I appreciate any help that is given to me, if there is anything that I can do to make this a "better" question, please tell me.

Comment: Are you trying to store the experience variable in a file, so it persists between games, or trying to define it in a module and make it global to all three modules? Assuming it's the later, you should define chunks of functionality in modules, import them and then pass your global into their functions and methods. Each module has it's own namespace with its own variables. That's really the point of a *module*.

Comment: Until you start defining classes, just put functions in modules, and import them. Try and write your functions so that they work based entirely on their arguments and locals [stuff defined within the function itself], keeping globals to a minimum. Only big, important stuff should ever be global. Start by turning your file1.py into a function. If `game` and `check_experience` are in other files, import them and have their modules be global in file1.py.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. I'm still having trouble, however. So right now the problem that I'm having. The variables are not changing throughout different functions. For example: I have the experience variable in "File2". "File1", is a function (the main game loop) and at the top has "global experience". So (just for testing) if I press "5", I get 500 experience. Now, going into "File3", a minigame, I get 100 experience from that. If I go back into "File1" and print(experience) it equals 500. Not 600. If I go to "File3" and print(experience) it gives me 100.

Comment: If I just put "global experience" at the top of every page and every function, shouldn't this stop this from happening?

Comment: No, you'd have three different variables in three different modules. You import the minigame function, like `from file1 import minigame`, then use it's return value, the minigame score, to update your global, `experience += minigame()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your minigame function and use that to update the experience variable that'll be a global in your main file.

`/main.py`

```
from minigame import game
exp = 0
exp += game()
print(exp)
```

`/minigame.py`

```
def game():
    '''This function can not reference `exp`. If `exp` were defined in
    this module, it'd be a different `exp` in a different namespace.'''
    score = 0
    ...
    return score
```

Comment: Ah, I understand. That's a bit of a pain if I want to have a lot of variables, though . Now, I have one more question. (sorry!) Let's say that the the game has a lot of variables. (mostly just statistic stuff, like questions_right, questions_wrong, total_score, points_earned, etc) If I wanted to print out those variables from my main.py file, would that be possible? I would eventually like to get to add other games as well which will have their own statistic variables and want to print them ALL from the main.py file.

Comment: Sorry. This isn't really the best forum for this kind of thing. You should sign up for CodeAcademy or something like that. SO is not set up for offering this kind of support. All the best with it.